# Finding missing data or Comparing Whole rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure how to word the title, but I've been trying to write a query for the last 2 days which is getting me frustrated. Please see my table structure below:

```
----------------------
|      TABLE A       |
----------------------
| FIELD 1 |  FIELD 2 |
----------------------
|   X     |    A     |
|   X     |    B     |
|   Y     |    C     |
|   Y     |    D     |
|   Y     |    E     |
|   Z     |    F     |
---------------------

----------------------
|      TABLE B       |
----------------------
| PK FIELD | FIELD 2 |
----------------------
|    1     |    X    |
|    2     |    Y    |
|    3     |    Z    |
----------------------
           1
           |
           |
           |
           *
------------------------
|        TABLE C       |
------------------------
| FK FIELD  | FIELD 1  |
------------------------
|     1     |     A    |
|     1     |     B    |
|     2     |     C    |
|     2     |     D    |
|     3     |     E    |
------------------------
```

OK, so basically, Table A's data is imported into the DB and is used as a reference to ensure the data that was manually added to Table B and Table C are correct. Table A has no relationships to any other table. Table B and Table C have a one to many relationship between each other (Table B being on the 'one' side).

Now what I'm trying to write a select query which will list all the items from Table B joined to Table C where [Table B].[Field 2] = [Table A].[Field 1] but where [Table C].[Field 1] is NOT the same as [Table A].[Field 2].

The results I'm expecting (as with the data above) is:

- Y, as it is not linked to E
- Z, as it is linked to E instead of F

This is what I have tried (among other things):

```
SELECT     [Table B].[Field 2], [Table C].[Field 1], [Table A].[Field 2] AS CorrectItem
FROM         [Table B] INNER JOIN
                      [Table C] ON [Table B].[Field 2] = [Table C].[Field 1] INNER JOIN
                      [Table A] ON [Table B].[PK Field] = [Table A].[FK Field] AND 
                      [Table C].[Field 1] <> [Table A].[Field 2]
ORDER BY [Table B].[Field 2]
```

but this is obviously wrong as it is giving me all the possible combinations where the data could be wrong.

I am at a loss and I'm sure it is something simple, but I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `TableA` is what you should have and `TableC *--1 TableB` is what you do have.

What you have can be converted into the same format as TableA like this:

```
SELECT TableB.Field2 As Field1, TableB.Field1 As Field2
FROM TableB
JOIN TableC on TableB.FkField = TableC.PkField
```

Now you can use this to subtract these rows (what you do have) from TableA (what you should have).  Whatever remains are rows that you should have but do not:

```
    SELECT Field1, Field2
    FROM TableA
EXCEPT
    SELECT TableB.Field2 As Field1, TableB.Field1 As Field2
    FROM TableB
    JOIN TableC on TableB.FkField = TableC.PkField
```

Comment: Doh! Complete forgot about the except keyword... thanks a million! I'll give it a try and let you know, but I'm sure it'll do the trick!